# Qualifier not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired, qualifiers

CallingApp.java

```
@Service
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.codegeekslab.type" })
public class CallingApp {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("BasicPhone")
    private Phone phone;

    public CallingApp(Phone phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void makeCall(int number) {
        phone.openApp(number);
    }

}
```

Phone.java

```
package com.geekslab.device;

public interface Phone {

    public void openApp(int number);

}
```

BasicPhone.java

```
package com.codegeekslab.type;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.geekslab.device.Phone;
@Component("BasicPhone")
 public class BasicPhone implements Phone {
    {
        System.out.println("BasicPhone");
    }

    public void openApp(int number) {
        System.out.println("calling via simcard... " + number);
    }

}
```

SmartPhone.java

```
package com.codegeekslab.type;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.geekslab.device.Phone;

@Component("SmartPhone")
public class SmartPhone implements Phone {
    {
        System.out.println("SmartPhone");
    }

    public void openApp(int number) {
        System.out.println("calling via whatsapp..." + number);
    }

}
```

Test.java

```
package com.codegeekslab.test;

 import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.codegeekslab.app.CallingApp;
import com.codegeekslab.type.BasicPhone;
import com.codegeekslab.type.SmartPhone;
import com.geekslab.device.Phone;

 public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //ApplicationContext context =
        //      new GenericXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        //SpringHelloWorld helloSpring  = context.getBean("springHelloWorld", SpringHelloWorld.class);
        //comment this for xml less spring 
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
         context.scan("com.codegeekslab.app","com.codegeekslab.type");
        //context.register( BasicPhone.class,SmartPhone.class,CallingApp.class);
         context.refresh();
        CallingApp  callingApp  = context.getBean("callingApp", CallingApp.class);  
        callingApp.makeCall(99999);

    }
}
```

Even though i am giving qualifier as   `@Qualifier("BasicPhone")` in `CallingApp` class ,I am getting **Exception** as follows:

> No qualifying bean of type [com.geekslab.device.Phone] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: BasicPhone,SmartPhone

Comment: Could you remove `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.codegeekslab.type" })` from your service class then try??

Comment: @SachinSarawgi got the answer,thnaks anyways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pass phone as a constructor argument in your CallingApp service without specifying the bean.

Try either to put a qualifier at your constructor or stick to the autowire injection which is something your already do.

Answer (score 0):

i removed the CallingApp class constructor and it worked.

```
 public CallingApp(Phone phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }
```

As Constructor was overriding the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add no argument constructor

```
public CallingApp(){
    //do nothing
}
public CallingApp(Phone phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```